# images are broken on some of the MVC pages

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I cannot see the image tec.png on Print.cshtml but same image is visible on PrintBos.cshtml

[image: cshtml files]

[image: My image path]

Print.cshtml code

```
<th>
        <img style="
             width:60%;
             "src="..\img\tec.png">
    </th>
```

printBos.cshtml code

```
<th>
        <img style="
             width:60%;
             "src="..\img\tec.png">
    </th>
```

As I can see,they are the same. What might be the reason?

**Edit**: I realized that images are shown on the default page only and using `~` doesn't work. Image file contents are not encrypted.

Comment: try setting the url as ~/img/tec.png

Comment: @jao now both not working...

Comment: are you using any server side technolgy, like .net core? if not, change it back to what you had and post the contents of your css file

Comment: it is an ASP.NET Core web Application @jao

Comment: Your slashes are going the wrong way. This is the internet, not Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `..` and it worked

```
 <th>
            <img style="
                 width:60%;
                 "src="\img\tec.png">
        </th>
```

Comment: if your website is going to be installed in a virtual directory it will stop working. assuming this is .net core, add app.UseStaticFiles() to your program.cs (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You should then be able to use <img src="~/img/tec.png" />. 

I think your PrintBos.cshtml is now being called from a url like domain.ext/dir/page and the Print.cshtml is called from domain.ext/page. The `~/` will make it always relative to the root of your app

Comment: app.UseStaticFiles() didn't work as well... @jao

Comment: hard to say whats wrong then without additional code

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the path to the image file is incorrect or the file is missing in the location specified.

You can try out the following steps may it help you out,

Verify that the path to the image file is correct in the Print.cshtml file. Also check for any typos or mistakes in the file path.

Next check if the image file exists or not for this go to the location specified in the Print.cshtml file and verify if the image file actually exists or not. If it does not, either upload the file or update the file path in the Print.cshtml file.

Also verify the format of the file because we need to make sure that the image file is in a format that can be displayed in a web page (such as PNG, JPG, or GIF).

As a last step check even if the image file exists, but image is still not visible, check the file permissions to ensure that it is accessible to the web server.

If these steps do not help and the issue is still there, you may need to further check out the code and configuration of your web application to find out the root cause.

Thanks.

Comment: How can i check the file permissions ? I guess images cannot be obtained from server since I can see them on the default page.

Comment: This is the answer to this question which gets asked every hour here on SO it seems. Also his slashes are going the wrong way.